Strange problem with textbox text location Visual Studio 2022
Visual Studio 2022 v17.10.3, Windows 11, C#, .NET 8, Winforms
Two screenshots will better explain the problem. I have TableLayoutPanel where each has been filled with a TextBox. In one section I have textboxes which are all identical except for Name and Location:
At design time:

After running the program I get this:

The lower left text box ALWAYS is offset when running the program.

Deleted the problem textbox and recreated in the designer (about 10 times).
Deleted the problem textbox and copied one of its mates to the original cell.
Moved the problem textbox to a different cell and created or copied a new text box to the problem cell.
Set a breakpoint when the textbox is activated and looked at the properties of the textbox (more than 100 of them). They are identical to what is set in the designer.
Prayed. Didn't help but I felt a bit better.

I don't fully expect an immediate solution; but what I am hoping for is some alternate ways to debug this issue. I've pretty much run out of ideas.
Thanks

Have you tried creating a minimally reproducible example? If it happens in a clean solution at least you'll know it's a framework issue. Also, this is a bit hacky, but you could try adjusting the font alignment after the initialisation of the form

Is it the TextBox that is in a different location or is it that the text is centred rather than right-aligned?

Delete the TableLayoutPanel and place a new one. Clear all the Rows of this new control, reset the Styles, then add the new Rows

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Not much code to show as I actually believe this is some sort of designer or initialization problem.   However there is a function called early where I have set a breakpoint so I could analyze the Properties right after the program starts and initializes.  The TextBot name is Rev_4_13 and has both margins and padding set to 0.  Sorry, don't know how to include images inline so here are two images who show those property values during run time.  https://www.firish.com/Properties1.jpg   https://www.firish.com/Properties2.jpg

@Jimi   I really don't want to rebuild the entire Panel as it is quite large and rather tedious to do.  The entire layout looks like this (sort of a poor man' custom Excel):  https://www.firish.com/TableLayoutPanel.jpg

As already mentioned by jmcilhinney, seems more like a justification issue than location. To ensure, check the designer and also add border to textboxes.

Then you can do a couple of things: - check the Designer.cs file of that form, see whether you spot some anomalies in the definition of the styles in that Row / Column - Drag the affected Control out of the TLP, enlarge the Row, then put the Control back, see whether it sticks to the upper-left corner of its Cell. If it doesn't, the TLP has gone rogue (metadata in the resource file has been corrupted, it happens. Replacing the TLP is mandatory). If it does stick in the right place, then set the Dock Property of the Control to Fill, see how it behaves. Readjust the Row's size after

SOLVED!  First, I would like to thank everyone who participated in this mis-adventure.  I really appreciate all the comments and suggestions.  Lots of insights, lots of troubleshooting trips, all incredibly helpful.   But basically if there was a Darwin Award of Programming Stupidity, I will certainly be a contestant for the new award.   It turns out I have a 'Clear Data' routine which resets all the data to the defaults values.  But then since I didn't really need it for the initial display, I just took out the call to it during initialization.  Except...  I didn't.   (more)

So finally I decided to look at the initialization and found that routine was called.  And then noticed that gee... the only parameter that had this behavior was always the same one, regardless of where I placed.  Oh, and because I used padding (0) and margin(0) it turnout that data was always a bit too close the right hand border so I 'padded' all that data with a blank space '$0.00 ' and gee, didn't that look nice.  Exept... in ONE line I had padded with THREE blank spaces '$0.00   ' (apparently some keyboard mischief) and an obvious find when you look at data.  Don't really see the (more)

extra blanks, do you?  So no esoteric TPL bug, no odd formatting bug, just me and my stupid old brain.  One might think "Oh, no problem!  Those kind of things happen to newbies all the time!" But I'm not much a newbie.  I took my first programming course in 1967 (!).  So apparently when you are on the other side of the age spectrum, you become somewhat of a newbie again.  Anyway... thanks again for all your help and sorry for your wasted time.

Hi ,Glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue!  See can I answer my own question, Just a reminder :) @jrj47

Try to manually add code to the initialize part of your problem TextBox, setting the Margin and Padding properties to 0, like this:
textBox.Margin = new Padding(0); 
textBox.Padding = new Padding(0);


@jcmilhinney   TextBox location is same in Designer as it is in runtime.

@The Lemon  I use the default font (Microsoft Sans Serif) and have since tried Courier New, Lucina Console and Verdana, all with the same miserable results.  I will see if I can make some minimal case where this still occurs.
